How to create an ENUM member in a parent ENUM class? For class methods referencing a default value
This is more to stop the linter yelling at me, but I'd like to include an ENUM member [BLANK] in the parent ENUM inherited by every child class.
I have an ENUM parent (ENUM_Blank) that contains a class method (FromStringToENUM), which converts a list ENUMs with a Blank prefixed if the list is greater than 1 (among other things). Every ENUM child class inherits this method and has the first value be BLANK. In the code this works fine. But the linter complains that the parent class doesnt have BLANK defined, and Id prefer it stops.
So I need a way to tell the linter that the parent class always has BLANK as a member, and better yet enforce that all children of this class has BLANK as a member (though they needn't be comparable, Im not comparing COLORs and ANIMALs, just sharing this function).
Code that works but Linter yells (at the cls.BLANK part):
class ENUM_Blank(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def FromStringToENUM(cls, stringList: list[str]) ->list[ENUM_Blank]:
        fixedList = []
        if len(stringConvert) > 1: fixedList.append(cls.BLANK)
        [...]
        return fixedList

class COLOR(ENUM_Blank): #Inherits function
    BLANK = 'Blank'
    RED = 'Red'
    GREEN = 'Green'

class ANIMAL(ENUM_Blank): #Inherits function
    BLANK = 'Blank'
    CAT = 'Cat'
    DOG = 'Dog'

Preferred code:
class ENUM_Blank(Enum):
    BLANK = 'Blank'
    @classmethod
    def FromStringToENUM(): [...]

class COLOR(ENUM_Blank): #Inherits function AND has COLOR.BLANK
    RED = 'Red'
    GREEN = 'Green'

class ANIMAL(ENUM_Blank): #Inherits function AND has COLOR.BLANK
    CAT = 'Cat'
    DOG = 'Dog'


what you can do is uses a custom metaclass to automatically add the BLANK member to all enum classes that inherit from ENUM_Blank

Your claim that you have a working version is suspect, because you can't extend an Enum in Python.

I am not extending an ENUM in Python. I am creating a parent class with no members and a class method. Then creating a child class with members inheriting the class method.

How are you not extending an Enum? EnumBlank is an Enum, and it is the super for all you other Enums. What do you think extend means?

The parent lacks any members. You can try it yourself, any parent ENUM with no members can have child classes with members.

What linter are you using?
